# Container in Picker Menu Style

Tags: swiftui

If I put a HStack in the content of the picker I get tripled rows per HStack. How is it possible to put the content in one row?

Picker: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPY2A.jpg

```
struct ContentView: View{
    @State var number = 0
    var body: some View{
        Menu(content: {
            Picker(selection: $number, content: {
                Section{
                    ForEach(0..<5, content: {i in
                        HStack{
                            Image(systemName: "house")
                            Spacer()
                            Text("number: \(i)")
                        }
                        .tag(i)
                    })
                }
                Section{
                    HStack{
                        Image(systemName: "house")
                        Spacer()
                        Text("Section")
                    }
                    .tag(6)
                    
                }
            }, label: {EmptyView()})
            
        }, label: {
            Text("number: \(number)")
                .frame(width: 100, height: 30)
                .background(Color.green)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Pickers are meant to be single row objects, you will need something g custom for something bigger than that.

Comment: I think in iOS 14 it was possible to put a HStack in a row.

Comment: Not really sure I understood what do you want to achieve... would you add some screenshot or sketch?

Comment: The image the spacer and the text should be in one row.

Comment: Try to set the pickerStyle to what you want to achievers testing the different possibilités so you can learn.